# Working with graphics files and trying to rename sequentially with mv

Tags: mv

I have been looking an older question answering a similar question, but apparently I am not too good at making the code work.  I am on zsh not bash, but other bash shell scripts have worked fine, so I think that it is okay.

I have tried from prompt (inline)

```
$i=107;for i in *.jpg;do mv "$i" "$i.jpg" $i=$((i+1)); done
```

basically, I want the current name to become as follows:

107.jpg
108.jpg
109.jpg
110.jpg

etc to the end of the list.

Hope someone can help me with the code, was wanting to use seq I think?

Thnaks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use two separate variables for the index being incremented and the file name being processed:

```
i=107; for file in *.jpg; do mv "$file" "$((i++))".jpg; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `zsh`, you could avoid the explicit loop by using its `zmv` module:

```
autoload zmv

i=107; zmv -n '*.jpg' '$[i++].jpg'
```

Remove the `-n` once you are happy with the proposed operations.